# can auto type deduction possibly cause conversion error?

Tags: c++, g++, c++11

I have a very simple parser rule (for AXE), like this:

```
auto space = axe::r_lit(' ');
auto spaces = space & space & space;
```

The last line compiles and works as expected in VC2010, but gives a strange error in gcc 4.6:

```
parsers.cpp:68:34: error: conversion from 
'axe::r_and_t<
    axe::r_and_t<axe::r_char_t<char>&, axe::r_char_t<char>&>, 
    axe::r_char_t<char>&
>' to non-scalar type 
'axe::r_and_t<
    axe::r_and_t<axe::r_char_t<char>&, axe::r_char_t<char>&>&, 
    axe::r_char_t<char>&
>' requested
```

I wonder, whether it's a (known) bug in gcc, and whether it's even possible to get conversion errors with `auto` declaration. Shouldn't the deduced type for `auto` be always exactly the same type as the initializer?

AXE [overloads operator&](http://www.gbresearch.com/axe/Dox/axe__composite__function_8h_source.html) like this:

```
template<class R1, class R2>
r_and_t<
    typename std::enable_if<
       is_rule<typename std::remove_reference<R1>::type>::value, R1>::type, 
    typename std::enable_if<
       is_rule<typename std::remove_reference<R2>::type>::value, R2>::type
>
operator& (R1&& r1, R2&& r2)
{
    return r_and_t<R1, R2>(std::forward<R1>(r1), std::forward<R2>(r2));
}
```

I wasn't able to reduce the problem to a short test case, unfortunately every time I try to come with simple example, it compiles.

Comment: Do we know if the problem is with initializing the `auto` variable, or if it is one of the `&` operators having a problem with a temporary?

Comment: @Bo Persson: it looks like the problem is with `auto`, because this line: `space & space & space;` compiles without problems. Looking at the error message, compiler correctly identified the right side type, but for some reason decided to assign `auto` a different type, which resulted in conversion error.

Comment: It doesn't seem to have to do with `auto`, but with the fact that `R1` in your second `&`-use (`E & space`, where `E` is the rvalue result of the first `&` use) seems to be a `T&`, instead of a `T` (as required by C++0x). Smells like a GCC problem to me, right now.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub: yes, it looks like compiler missed the rvalue, but even with that why would it ever have different types on right- and left-hand side with `auto`?

Comment: @Gene the problem is not with `auto`, I think. It's with a mismatch between the type of the return expression and the return type of the second instantiation of `operator&`. But that indicates that `R1` would be a different type in the body of `operator&` than in the declaration section. Does it make a difference if you change `operator&` to use the `auto name() -> ...` notation? Just guessing...

Comment: EDIT: But then the error would not have pointed to the `auto` line, so I suspect the error is actually at the `auto` declaration.. I've no idea about that :)

Comment: Two more pieces of information: 1) changing `operator&` to use trailing return type didn't change error message; 2) the error on that line is the same even if variable `spaces` is not used at all.

Comment: And one more piece of information, the error occurs only if the function that contains those two lines is a template, even if template type is not used. If the function is not a template, then code compiles without error.

Answer (score 3):

`auto` is not always exactly the type of initializer, because `auto` is dropping references, making it type `T` where you would expect `T&`. If you need reference - spell `auto&`.

Comment: That is correct, I should have phrased it more precisely as *deduced from initializer* instead of using *the same type as the initializer*, because the *same* is subject to the type deduction rules, which vary for different language constructs. But the question is still the same, compiler seem to have deduced the type differently during two phases of lookup, which I believe is a bug.

Answer (score 2):

***Don't rate this answer, it's for information purposes only***

This was indeed a bug in previous versions of gcc, it was fixed in gcc-4.7.0.

Comment: This should be up-voted and accepted as the correct answer, as it may help people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the references.

```
parsers.cpp:68:34: error: conversion from 
'axe::r_and_t<
    axe::r_and_t<axe::r_char_t<char>&, axe::r_char_t<char>&>, 
    axe::r_char_t<char>&
>' to non-scalar type 
'axe::r_and_t<
    axe::r_and_t<axe::r_char_t<char>&, axe::r_char_t<char>&>&, 
    axe::r_char_t<char>&
>' requested
```

The first template argument is `axe::r_and_t<axe::r_char_t<char>&, axe::r_char_t<char>&>` for the first one, and `axe::r_and_t<axe::r_char_t<char>&, axe::r_char_t<char>&>&` for the second. This is a template argument mismatch- probably in the return value. Most likely, it occurs because Visual Studio's SFINAE implementation is dodgy at best and it doesn't implement two-phase lookup properly, and it's possible that the GCC version is picking a different overload to Visual Studio.

Comment: The point is, there shouldn't be any problem at all if `auto` is used. Unless the problem is really with `space & space & space` -- but the OP says that this compiles OK as a stand-alone line.

Comment: Two pieces of information lead me to believe that it's a compiler error. First, it's hard to envision how `auto` can possibly lead to this error. Second, this error only appears in template code. Gcc unlike VC10 implements two phase lookup, and probably somehow it deduced type differently in the two phases.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking the compiler at its word, with this version:

```
axe::r_and_t<
axe::r_and_t<axe::r_char_t<char>&, axe::r_char_t<char>&>, 
axe::r_char_t<char>&
> spaces = space & space & space ;
```

What happens?

**Edited to add:** I just noticed that this question is three months old. So never mind. But did it ever get resolved?

Comment: I tend to believe it's a compiler error. I didn't have a chance to try more recent version of gcc. There are no errors if actual type is used instead of `auto`, there isn't error if an `auto` declared in non-template function either. My guess it's compiler two phase lookup bug, when the type inferred during the first pass differs from the type inferred during instantiation.